# "The given key was not present in the dictionary." when adding Association to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, view

[image: Entity Diagram]

Using EF6 / VS 2013, I have created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model.  This model uses three views, stored in SQL Server, to prepare the data in a suitable form from an existing system.  One for Users (vw_Users), one for Roles (vw_Roles) and a cross-reference/association view (vw_UserRoles).

When the User and Role entities are mapped, the application compiles and executes without issue.  However, when I add the Association between User and Role and map it to the vw_UserRoles view, I get an EntityCommandCompilationException with an inner exception, KeyNotFoundException {"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}.

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
```

To me it just feels like a bug but I am new to a lot of the EF and it could be to do with connecting to views.  Out of interest I implemented this trick to [treat the view as a table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx) but it made no difference.

UPDATE #1: I created a new web application with a new SQL Server database.  I created the underlying tables with relationships and a view for each table.  When I create a entity model based on the tables, I have no problems -- even with the association.  When I created a model from the views, I get the KeyNotFoundException.  Note: I have corrected the keys and added and mapped the association on the second, view-based model.  You can download the project from here - http://sdrv.ms/1eZ7ytp

UPDATE #2: I have logged this as an issue with MS @ Codeplex - https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1777

I'm still stumped on this one and am really keen to complete this using a series of views.  Any thoughts?  Please....?

---

Full Exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232005
  Message=An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindInStore(WrappedEntityKey key, String keyValuesParamName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at Mind.Mindlink.Portal.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Mind.Mindlink.Portal\Mind.Mindlink.Portal\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 13
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()
  InnerException: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
   HResult=-2146232969
   Message=The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
        at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.MemberDomainMap.GetDomainInternal(MemberPath path)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.MemberDomainMap.GetDomain(MemberPath path)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQueryKB.CreateIsOfTypeCondition(MemberPath currentPath, IEnumerable`1 derivedTypes, MemberDomainMap domainMap)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQueryKB.CreateAssociationConstraints(EntitySetBase extent, MemberDomainMap domainMap, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewgenContext..ctor(ViewTarget viewTarget, EntitySetBase extent, IList`1 extentCells, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, ConfigViewGenerator config, MemberDomainMap queryDomainMap, MemberDomainMap updateDomainMap, StorageEntityContainerMapping entityContainerMapping)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.CreateViewgenContext(EntitySetBase extent, ViewTarget viewTarget, CqlIdentifiers identifiers)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateDirectionalViewsForExtent(ViewTarget viewTarget, EntitySetBase extent, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, KeyToListMap`2 views)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateDirectionalViews(ViewTarget viewTarget, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, KeyToListMap`2 views)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateAllBidirectionalViews(KeyToListMap`2 views, CqlIdentifiers identifiers)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewgenGatekeeper.GenerateViewsFromCells(List`1 cells, ConfigViewGenerator config, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, StorageEntityContainerMapping containerMapping)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewgenGatekeeper.GenerateViewsFromMapping(StorageEntityContainerMapping containerMapping, ConfigViewGenerator config)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGenerateViews(StorageEntityContainerMapping entityContainerMap, Dictionary`2 resultDictionary)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGetGeneratedViews(EntityContainer container)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace, StorageMappingItemCollection storageMappingItemCollection)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(Node scanTableNode, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ScanTableOp op, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitSortOp(SortBaseOp op, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(ConstrainedSortOp op, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ConstrainedSortOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitPhysicalOpDefault(PhysicalOp op, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo, Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(DbCommandTree ctree, List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   InnerException:
```

Comment: Did you create or modify the edmx manually? No association is defined in the SSpace and I suspect this is the source of the error.

Comment: @Pawel I'll have a look.  I didn't create or modify the edmx; this was created by Visual Studio (which is a tad disturbing).  What is the SSpace?  Is this the mapping in the schema?

Comment: SSpace = Store Space - the way the database is described under StorageModels in the edmx. I will try to look into this a bit more tomorrow.

Comment: No worries @Pawel.  If you plan to look into it, download the project I put together.  It has two models - both generated by the EDMX builder - one looking at tables, one looking at views.  http://sdrv.ms/1eZ7ytp

I am convinced it is a bug (or something I am doing with the Association)...

Comment: I was able to repro this earlier today using the project you attached to the work item you filed (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1777)

Comment: I tried to reverse engineer views from the database you provided and ended up having 3 entities without any associations. I must be doing something wrong and the issue does not repro. (to clarify - I am able to repro the runtime bug with the edmx you provided in the repro project, but not the bug in the designer where it apparently builds an incorrect model).

Comment: Because they are views, after creating the entities from the database, you need to manually identify the PK and associations.  It is at the point of creating and mapping the association to a view that the error occurs.

Comment: thanks for clarification. So basically, after creating model from db you had 3 entities and then you manually modified the model with the designer to define the many to many association. Will be looking more into it tomorrow.

Comment: Yes.  I removed one entity and added an association.  The entity I removed was a cross-reference view used as mapping for the association.

Comment: This is a regression in EF6. It's now assigned to a member of the EF team for fix.

Comment: I'm also getting this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Identified as a regression as part of the initial EF6 release.

Thanks for reviewing the project for me, @Pawel.  If you can put a comment on the CodePlex issue, that would likely aid in it getting some priority.  http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1777

On one hand I am happy the issue is repeatable and a likely bug.  On the other hand, I just want to get on with doing this in EF 6.  I have resorted to completing this in VS 2012 using EF 5 for the meantime.  I will update if I uncover anything else.

Comment: As of today, this is marked as Closed (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1777) and resolved in EF6.0.2.  This will be released as a NuGet release shortly.  The EF designer in VS will still show an error if you use the nightly builds, but this too will be resolved shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. When the model was originally created the EF version used was 5. Now using VS 2012 and EF6. Don't want to roll back to EF5.

Comment: If you found the information in line with your issue, then +1 it so it will appear more easily for others with the same issue and hopeful get addressed.  

It seems to me to be a reasonable issue, particularly for people looking to upgrade EF5 models who had to use views to present data in a EF-friendly format from existing databases.