# Scaffolding error after upgrade to MVC5 / EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

After upgrading, when I try to add a scaffold View I get the following error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to
>   retrieve metadata for 'Data.Technical.TechJob'. The given key was not
>   present in the dictionary.'

Does anyone have any ideas what's causing this or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The given key was not present in the dictionary." when adding Association to Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631162/the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-when-adding-association-to-en)

Comment: I've tried upgrading to the latest beta version of EF (6.0.2-beta1) but still get the same error when trying to scaffold a view.

Comment: Close and restart Visual Studio and try again.

Comment: Tried that twice Chris. Everything else is working, I can manually create the view and everything is building without errors or warnings. It's just the scaffolding that's failing. Is there any way I can troubleshoot the scaffolding process to see where it is failing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it reports a bug that can better be committed to the product's support site.